# DFSR and site link

Tags: active-directory, dfs-r

From my understanding, DSF uses the site/link information created in Active Directory Site and Services to redirect users to the nearest fileserver (when, of course, users access the share via the DFS namespace).

What about DFSR? Lets pretend that I have a two sites domain. Would DFSR replicate only with ADSS-configured link interval and schedule? For example, having a 15 min ADSS link interval would limit DFSR to a 15-min interval? Or would be the replication as fast as possible, as selected in the DFSR wizard when creating the replication group?

Answer (score 2):

Things are actually much worse than that: DFS-R won't replicate even within configured time interval, just because files might be open.